# Resume suspended USB device

Tags: usb, webcam

For some reason, my iSight wasn't working, so I used USB Prober.app to reveal that the device was suspended. Is there a way to resume the device (without rebooting)?

Comment: Usually unplug and plug back into a different USB port.

Comment: @da4 The iSight camera is an inbuilt camera, even though it uses a USB port.

Comment: Sorry, assumed you meant the older external version, which I now remember was FireWire 400 anyway.  Sounds like it'll require a restart.